# Multi Auth with Roles and Permissions

Tags: laravel

I have 4 Separate sections as logins

Admin Login
Vendor Login
Employee Login
User Login

Admin is supposed to create all roles and permissions to these different  Type of Users

How should i maintain the roles and permissions tables

Can i have only two tables such as roles and permissions to manage all these User Types

Answer (score -1):

```
  yes you have to create four tables.1 permissions,2 permission_roles,3 users and 4 user_roles table.
    for define role you can use this code in login function.i hope it will help you.
     if (isset($_SESSION['user']['user_id'])) {
                if ($_SESSION['user']['group_slug'] == 'Admin') {
                    return redirect('admin/dashboard');
                } else if ($_SESSION['user']['group_slug'] == 'Vendor') {
                  return redirect('Vendor/dashboard');
                } else if ($_SESSION['user']['group_slug'] == 'Employee') {
                      return redirect('Employee/dashboard');
                } else if ($_SESSION['user']['group_slug'] == 'User') {
                 return redirect('User/dashboard');
                }
            }
```

Comment: What if i wan to maintain separate roles and permissions table for each Employee, Vendor etc....